# Python Okta and Office 365/ SharePoint

Tags: python, api, sharepoint, office365, okta

I would like to pick a file from SharePoint using a python script. The problem is that my company is using Okta to secure identity and I don't really know which is the right approach to connect through Okta to Office 365. Has anyone had any experience on this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Hi, How did you achieve it, Stuck in the same issue, Please help me,